# regex for multi-delimiter string in create hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hiveql

I ask for your help

When I created a hive table, The data is as follows.

data file

```
<__name__>abc
<__code__>1
<__value__>1234
<__name__>abcdef
<__code__>2
<__value__>12345
<__name__>abcdef
<__code__>2
<__value__>12345
1234156321
<__name__>abcdef
<__code__>2
<__value__>12345
...
```

can i create a table right away without converting the file?

Comment: the format you're showing is plain text ? each new line is a column, and each group of 3 lines is a new line ? Am i understanding it right ?

Comment: newlines will create rows

Comment: Yes, it's a plain text file, Three columns are repeated.